# Does there exist a graph G of order 10 and size 28 that is not Hamiltonian?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I dont know how to tackle this problem. I can not think of anyway to start it, i cannot apply Dirac's equation to it because there will be many graphs of different degree sequence. But i have a graph in which one of this vertex has degree 4 which is less than the half of number of vertices. Is this right? Or is there any other way?

Comment: This is exercise $6.22$ [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=zA_CAgAAQBAJ&pg=SA6-PA23&lpg=SA6-PA23&dq=Does+there+exist+a+graph+G+of+order+10+and+size+28+that+is+not+Hamiltonian?&source=bl&ots=PGznNL5S-I&sig=F06KT0mO9bCwJhUoYsG_Jar1gOc).

Comment: Does *size* mean number of edges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a connected one that is obviously not hamiltonian.

[image]

In general: take your favorite graph on $9$ vertices and $27$ edges. Add one vertex and connect it to the rest. Done.

Answer (score 2):

Dirac's theorem is a sufficient condition. So if it is not satisfied we can't say anything about Hamiltonicity of given graph.

An easy idea to make non-Hamiltonian graph is making graph disconnected. If you make a vertex of degree 0 and any set of edges on remaining 9 vertices you'll definitely get a non-Hamiltonian graph.

EDIT. There is also even 4-connected non-Hamiltonian graph on 10 vertices with 30 edges:
[image]

Comment: The other component will still remain hamiltonian?

Comment: Yes, but this is not the only possible idea. It is possible to make connected non-Hailtonian graph on 10 vertices with 28 edges.